# child node locate lower than where it should be

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0P1B.png

the image about is what i see in chrome.

the circle with a number 4 inside, should be just right in the box with orange color around.

the circle element is without margin style.

you may find the live html code in http://sneezry.com

i hope you can understand what i mean :S

parent style:

```
.disqus_count {
    margin: 2px 20px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

child style:

```
.disqus_count a {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="disqus_count"><a href="http://sneezry.com/2013/11/02/%e6%88%91%e4%b9%9f%e5%8a%a8%e5%8a%a8%e5%b0%8f%e6%8c%87%e5%a4%b4#disqus_thread">4</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the child's display style to 'block' instead of 'inline-block', it should remove the extra space.